# Show Previous Statement while debugging with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to the show the previous statement in the method that I'm debugging with Visual Studio 2008?

What I'm currently doing is dragging the yellow arrowhead to the previous statement location or scrolling there and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>

But with some large methods the current statement might be quite a few lines upwards and it will really speed-up my debugging if I can press a shotcut key to jump to the previously executed statement.

I can jump to the previous method using the Call Stack <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> but how do I jump to the previous statement?

Edit: This might sound like a stupid question if the method is small, I mean, uhmm, the previous executed statement will probably be right above the currently executed statement, but if it is a large method (I know we should refactor those large methods!) then between the current statement and the previously executed statement might be a couple of lines for example switch or if statements etc.
So it takea a few seconds (sorry maybe I'm lazy?) to first scroll back and look for the previously executed statement if I for example want to execute that again.

Anyway I think the new [Visual Studio 2010 IntelliTrace (Historical Debugger)](http://blogs.msdn.com/habibh/archive/2009/06/18/an-in-depth-look-at-the-historical-debugger-in-visual-studio-2010-part-i.aspx) might have that functionality, so I'll ave a look at that.

Comment: i don't see that using the call stack is an onerous task

Comment: Mitch, using the call stack I can only go to previous methods, I want to go the previous statement in the same method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool I've tried it Visual Studio 2010 RC and it is possible (Unfortunately VS2010 Ultimate only).

See MSDN page ["Navigating with IntelliTrace"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264933%28VS.100%29.aspx)

*"Go to Previous Call or IntelliTrace Event moves the instruction pointer and debugging context backward in time to the last call or event."*

There's even Up and Down and Return buttons in the Navigation Gutter